# What is meant by end-to-end fashion convolutional neural network(CNN)?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

What is meant by end-to-end fashion convolutional neural network(CNN)which i had read in an image colorization paper?

Comment: Link to paper....

Answer (score 5):

**End-to-end** just means, that everything is learned by the CNN (as one big task) an there is no decapsulated extra-step like Feature-extraction with Gabor-filters for example.

Here is some excerpt from some [popular slides](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~yann/talks/lecun-ranzato-icml2013.pdf) (nice introduction) and there are more pages describing classic non-end-to-end pipelines nowadays replaced by end-to-end-approaches.

[image]
 <sup>*From "Deep Learning Tutorial" / LeCun, Ranzato*</sup>